# PHP парсинг кривого xml

Tags: php, парсер, xml

Есть такой вывод, через print_r выглядит так:

```
<response >
<ISSipExtensions><ISSipExtension>
<ISVoiceRegDNID>43</ISVoiceRegDNID>
</ISSipExtension>
</ISSipExtensions>
</response>
</axl>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Подскажите как просто и быстро достать в данном случае 43

Еще один пример кривого вывода, тут надо доставать 0:

```
<response xsi:type="ISexecCLIResponse" >
<ISexecCLIResponse>0</ISexecCLIResponse>
<ISexecCLIError></ISexecCLIError>
</response>
</axl>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Любой xml парсер. Правда, у Вас xml не очень валидный

Comment: Да, я это понял, что он кривой, поэтому и спросил, буду пробовать

Comment: ну как всегда, можно регулярочкой попробовать, но может не взлететь. - `$re = '/<ISVoiceRegDNID>(\d+)<\/ISVoiceRegDNID>/m';`

Comment: Думал об этом, но хочу сначала получить правильный результат, а потом уже похожие куски загнать в функцию, тогда регулярные выражения пригодятся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось конечно топорно, буду рад, если кто то покажет как можно это было решить не так прямолинейно

```
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['</axl>', '</SOAP-ENV:Body>', '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'], '', $response);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);

$ISVoiceRegDNID = $xml->ISSipExtensions->ISSipExtension->ISVoiceRegDNID;

echo $ISVoiceRegDNID;

43
```

Во втором случае мне мешает `<response xsi:type="ISexecCLIResponse">`, просто добавил еще один параметр в замену:

```
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['</axl>', '</SOAP-ENV:Body>', '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>', 'xsi:'], '', $response);
```